# Simulate proxy localy

Tags: php, proxy, stream, localhost

I'm using a PHP script that uses `stream_context`. I need to test it with a proxy. How can I simulate a proxy on my Mac for tests on my `localhost` *(I'm using MAMP)*. I downloaded `SquidMan` but I don't know if this is a good solution.

In my script I have to write something like this :

```
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'http', 'proxy', 'tcp://local-proxy:8080');
// how to create a local proxy ?
```

Thanks

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/42813/looking-for-http-debugging-proxy-for-mac-similar-to-fiddler-on-windows

Comment: @MyHeadHurts, is it really what I'm looking for ? I don't want to sniff packets through a network but create a proxy on my machine.

Comment: You should be able to use the tools to create a proxy. I use [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) for Windows - which is a web debugging proxy - but the functionality is there to use it as a proxy on your machine. I'm sure other tools for Mac will offer similar features.